# In octave, error: for x^A, A must be a square matrix. Use .^ for elementwise power

Tags: octave

In Octave I defined a function in a separate file square.m

```
function y = square(x)
y = x^2;
endfunction
```

In other file script.m I have

```
disp("Hello World 2");
fplot( @(x) square(x),[-1 1])
```

And I get
error: for x^A, A must be a square matrix.  Use .^ for elementwise power.

Also if I try

```
y = x.^2;
```

inside the function I get the exact same message

Comment: If I use   power(x,2)   I keep getting same error message

Comment: do you have the same problem with the script here: https://octave-online.net/bucket~RLpS1Vewci6ZtmLuYHMisZ ?

Comment: If you changed your function to use `.^` and you still get the error, it means that your functions wasn’t reloaded. Make sure Octave is aware of the new definition!

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting that error is because `fplot` is passing the range you specified all at once as a vector, treating your function as a vectorised function, expecting a vector input and returning a vector output.

You can confirm this by turning "debug on error" to true, by doing `debug_on_error(true)`, run the offending line, and inspect `x`.

Therefore, inside your function, things go wrong, because you're trying to get the square of a vector, which is an illegal operation (mathematically speaking).

Converting your function to `y = x.^2` should work in this case, because you'd be converting each element of the vector to its square, which is what you want. But obviously, simply changing `^` to `.^` might not work for every problem.

In general, it's better to create your own 'range' and 'outputs' and plot them directly using `plot`; this gives you far more control, and you can inspect the inputs and outputs first to ensure you're plotting what you think you're plotting.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

I have just tried your code on https://octave-online.net/ (no need to create an account nor even the files).

The second version works "as expected": `y = x .^ 2;` inside the function.

Make sure you saved the file after the modification?

Comment: Did you mean `.^`?